# What does the query parameter "sub_confirmation=1" do on a YouTube link?

Tags: youtube

I recently came across a link to a YouTube video with

```
?sub_confirmation=1
```

appended to the link.

What does this do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this does is automatically subscribe the follower of the link to the YouTube channel that posted the video.

It's not totally silent as it will popup a confirmation dialog:

[image]

so the user can choose what to do.

It's not a very nice thing to do though.

[Source](https://medium.com/@AndrewLeeReal/how-to-get-more-youtube-subscribers-by-making-a-channel-subscribe-link-90742f43e944)